# Hibernate keeps looking for configuration file in a different location

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate

I built my project using the Eclipse IDE, and placed my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in the `resources` folder (screenshot below):

[image]

---

The problem occurs when I try to reference `hibernate.cfg.xml` in my DAO classes. Here is a snippet of my code where I get my `SessionFactory`:

**DAO getSessionFactory() example**

```
private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        String hibernatePropsFilePath = "src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml";
        File hibernatePropsFile = new File(hibernatePropsFilePath);

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure(hibernatePropsFile);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(MyClass.class);

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();

        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
```

As you can see, I'm still pointing to the "correct" location in my project, however when I test using Postman, I get the following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Specified
>   cfg.xml file
>   [C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\src\main\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml] does
>   not exist

**My question**: *Why is it constantly looking in my Desktop for my file path, and how do I change it to look only in my project?* I checked and made sure that my resources path is present in my Web Deployment Assembly (screenshot below):

[image]

Comment: Did you try without specifying the path? Just use `Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());`

Comment: @ChetanJadhavCD this works, thank you! Strange as to why it does work now (tried this a long time ago)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`src/main` is maven specific project structure to arrange the source files. But after build the compiled classes and resource files are copied to `WEB-INF/classes/` directory.

Assuming you are using `maven` and your `resources` folder is part of the `source` structure, then the XML file will be copied to `WEB-INF/classes/resources` folder.

Change the path to `String hibernatePropsFilePath = "/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml";`

**Update:**

After taking a second look at your `Web Deployment Assembly` settings image, your `main/resources` folder is mapped to `classes` directory not `classes/resources`. so change the code as shown below without use of `File`.

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(ClientCrossRef.class);` 
    configuration.configure();
```

and even more better thing is, since your `cfg.xml` file is already part of classpath, you don't even need to specify it. Hibernate will look for it in the classpath.

And by the way, you can build the session factory easily as

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(
                    "hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Tried that, now I'm getting a: `HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Specified cfg.xml file [C:\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml] does not exist`. I noticed that the default directory for the File class is C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop. Could that also be the issue?

Comment: @TheApprentice You should never use `java.io.File` in a web application. The Hibernate `Configure.configure()` method also accepts a URL. You can call `getClass().getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml")` to get the appropriate URL.

Comment: Thank you @markbernard and K139. I appreciate both detailed answers and explanations. Already took notes on this and my application is running as intended.